# Java inherited method with generics argument type not found by reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Java inherited method with generics argument type not found by reflection. e.g.,

```
class Foo<X> {
   X name;

   public X getName() {}
   public void setName(X name) {}
}

class Bar extends Foo<String> {
   
}
```

get method using reflection:

```
Bar.class.getMethod("setName", String.class)
```

Error

```
NoSuchMethodException
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to type erasure, you need to use

```
Bar.class.getMethod("setName", Object.class);
```

to get that `Method`.

**Details**

As you may know, the Java compiler implements generics through a process called type erasure. Briefly put, this means that generics are a compile time feature, and erased during the translation to bytecode. That is, as far as the JVM is concerned, the code becomes

```
class Foo {
   Object name;

   public Object getName() {}
   public void setName(Object name) {}
}

class Bar extends Foo {
   
}
```

(Ok, the method actually contains two parameter signatures, a generic one saying that the parameter is of type `T` where `T` is type variable, and legacy one saying that the parameter is of type `Object` - and it is this latter signature that is matched if you call `getMethod(name, parameterClasses)`. However, since the subclass doesn't override the method, it doesn't contribute a method signature with the more specific type.)

You can read the JVM's mind by doing

```
        for (var m : Bar.class.getMethods()) {
            if (m.getName().equals("setName")) {
                System.out.println(m.toString());
                System.out.println(m.toGenericString());
            }
        }
```

which prints

```
public void Foo.setName(java.lang.Object)
public void Foo.setName(X)
```

Comment: Printing out Foo.setName(x), Is generics info still available at runtime? Thanks

Comment: Generics are retained in declared types so we can use compiled classes when writing new code, and since they are there, the reflection API allows us to look at them.

Comment: The Java Virtual Machine Specification [writes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se19/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9.1): "Signatures encode declarations written in the Java programming language that use types outside the type system of the Java Virtual Machine. They support reflection and debugging, as well as compilation when only class files are available."

Comment: Erasure removes generics but available at runtime? I am confused. Thanks.